# Slow running of code in AWS for the first time

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-sagemaker

I am running my code on SageMaker, which runs my code slowly for the first time, but runs much faster the second time around. I guess there's something getting stored in the cache. Few days back, it was running with the same speed all the time. What could be a possible solution for this?

```py
count_hea = 0
count_pleth = 0
for subfile in sorted(os.listdir('physionet.org/files/mimic3wdb-matched/1.0/p00')):
    count_hea = 0
    if subfile.startswith('p'):
        for subsubfile in sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join('physionet.org/files/mimic3wdb-matched/1.0/p00/' , subfile))):
            if subsubfile.startswith('p') and count_hea == 0 and not subsubfile[:-4].endswith('n'):
                try:            
                    i = i + 1
                    print(subsubfile)
                    count_hea = count_hea + 1
                    strip = subsubfile[:-4]
                    record = wfdb.rdrecord('physionet.org/files/mimic3wdb-matched/1.0/p00/' + subfile + '/' + strip, channel_names = ['PLETH'], return_res = 16)
                    r = record.__dict__
                    print(r['sig_name'])
                    if r['sig_name'] != None:
                        if r['sig_name'][0] == 'PLETH':
                            count_pleth = count_pleth + 1
                            print(count_pleth)  
                except Exception:
                    pass
print(count_pleth)
```

Comment: Can you provide any more context about your code?

Comment: So, the thing is, I have to read folders like p00, p01, p02 .... p09 which approximately has 1000 files each. I need to check if the file has the parameter that i desire for. If it has, then increment the count. Do this for all 10 folders. Reading all these files take a lot of time, which earlier took just a few minutes. When I push similar data to my Deep learning model, again, it takes a lot of time. But, this happens only the first time any dataset is being read. This hasn't happened earlier.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow!

**Incorrect:**
So assuming you're calling your sagemaker endpoint from a lambda function you're experiencing a cold start. When a lambda function is first executed it doesn't have a container - once it's been executed it then has a container which will hang around for about 30 mins and be much faster to start.

**Updated Answer based on comments:** I think what you're seeing is model warmup time - essentially your model is being loaded/cached behind the scenes - I've just tested it and I see the same behavior on a model I just mounted on an endpoint.

Comment: Hello! i'm running by creating a notebook instance in sagemaker. Not from lambda. Like, initially it was running faster right from first execution of code, but oflate, over the past 1-2 days, I'm facing this issue.

Comment: So you can ping your model after deployment to make sure you get it warmed up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not just with the model being read. Assume I have a dataset. I need to count the number of files with a certain parameter among say, 1000 files. While iterating through the dataset itself, it takes a lot of time the first time. Basically speaking, any form of code (be it CNN model / normal code) takes a lot of time to run on AWS the first time.

Comment: Where is this dataset being loaded from, it's being run in a JNB?

Comment: It's run from the notebook instance itself. In the jupyter notebook, I place the files. I read it from there. The code also is in the notebook instance.

Comment: Hrmm, so is the delay on inference or the entire process?

Comment: The entire process itself. It was working fine till few days back, suddenly this is happening. It's delaying my data preprocessing work a lot.

Comment: Yeah gonna need which cell is running slowly buddy really to help any further.

Comment: Hello, I've added the code which I'm trying. I have the dataset in my notebook.